# Why is = different from LIKE when using utf8_unicode_ci index?

Tags: mysql, collation, equality, sql-like

I have a database table with column `name` defined as `VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` with a unique index. It contains the name `"Grosse"`.

The following statement returns no rows:

```
SELECT name FROM authors WHERE name LIKE 'Große' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'
```

I've tried both with and without the `COLLATE` addition (which is probably not necessary).

The following statement returns the correct row:

```
SELECT name FROM authors WHERE name = 'Große'
```

Why do I get different results, shouldn't both statements return the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LIKE` Operator performs a match Character by Character. Of Course `Große` and `Grosse` are not even equal in length, so it can't match.

Try `SELECT 'ß' LIKE 'ss' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'` and you will receive 'false' (0)

Try `SELECT 'ß' = 'ss' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'` and you will receive 'true' (1)

The same behaviour applies for whitespaces btw:

`'x' LIKE 'x '` will not match, while `'x'='x '` will match.

Please note, that `=` in mysql is *not* of the same meaning as `==` is in any programing language. `=` in mysql has the meaning of `.equal()`. If you want to *mime* the programming languages `==` you should perform a binary comparision: `SELECT BINARY 'ss'='ß'` -> false.